# How i can find identical files using a hash and then display the path to them and their access rights?

Tags: shell-script

```
find ./ -type f -print0|xargs -0 md5sum |sort -k1,32|uniq -w32 -D 

find "." -type f -printf  "%i %p %s %t  %M\n"
```

I have two unrelated scripts. I tried to connect them, but nothing works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first prints something like

```
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  ./one/two/a.txt
b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  ./some/c.txt
```

So we could continue by cutting off the first 34 characters, which leaves the paths, one per line. And if you have GNU xargs, that could then be processed with `xargs -d '\n'` which could run e.g. `ls` on them. Or `find`.

```
$ find ./ -type f -print0|xargs -0 md5sum |sort |uniq -w32 -D |cut -c35- |xargs -d '\n' ls -ld
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6 Apr 12 22:38 ./one/two/a.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6 Apr 12 22:38 ./some/c.txt

$ find ./ -type f -print0|xargs -0 md5sum |sort |uniq -w32 -D |cut -c35- |xargs -I{} -d '\n' find {} -printf  "%i %p %s %t  %M\n"
1706523 ./one/two/a.txt 6 Mon Apr 12 22:38:18.6494036350 2021  -rw-r--r--
1710394 ./some/c.txt 6 Mon Apr 12 22:38:24.8373114680 2021  -rw-r--r--
```

(`sort -k1,32` would sort on the first and 32nd space-separated field, not on the first 32 characters. The hash is at the start of the string, so the default sort should work.)

Note that if you have filenames with newlines in them, `xargs -d '\n'` won't do.  But if that's an issue, you'll need more modifications since the output of `md5sum` also changes when it encounters names like that. E.g. I get

```
$ md5sum $'new\nline'
\b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184  new\nline
```

with the leading backslash.

Comment: thanks a lot 
it'll realy help me